# Substituindo imagem atraves de um sgc manual

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma imagem e gostaria que a mesmo fosse substituída por outra quando o Administrador fizesse login no site e informasse o nome da imagem em um `input`.

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso utilizando o código em umas 50 imagens, cada uma dentro de uma `div`, e só apareceria a opção de substituir a imagem por outro quando o Administrador estivesse no painel de administração?

Código PHP com cadastro no banco ou JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

com PHP porque precisa ter um login e senha para o painel administrativo alem disso salvar a url para o imagem.

Comment: Considerando a pergunta, acho que essa é a única resposta possível...